# Mmenu is not working in galaxy tab2

Tags: jquery, galaxy-tab

When i incorporate Jquery Mmenu within Bootstrap to it works perfectly in all browser when I zoom in at browser but when I tested in galaxy tab in portrait mode the responsive menu is working at first time only.

Any ideas or approach for this issue?

**Jquery Mmenu :** http://mmenu.frebsite.nl

I express thank you all in advance.

Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. It's a bug in samsung's browser with needing the webkit prefix for transition end event(see [Android 4.1 change - transition and webkittransition defiend, how to properly determine name of transition end event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823188/android-4-1-change-transition-and-webkittransition-defiend-how-to-properly-de)).

You can make the following modifications to the mmenu source to fix this issue (lines 636 and 1337 in v3.0.2):

```
transition: (function() {
    var fake=document.createElement( 'div' ).style;
    if('webkitTransition' in fake){
        return 'webkitTransition';  
    }
    return 'transition' in fake;
})()
function transitionend( $e, fn, duration )
{
    //check to see if the browser supports webkitTransition if so, use that instead
    var transSupport=$.fn.mmenu.support.transition;
    if ( transSupport == 'webkitTransition')
    {           
        $e.one("webkitTransitionEnd",fn);
    }
    else if(transSupport){
        $e.one( _e.transitionend, fn );
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout( fn, duration );
    }
}
```

Comment: This fix is implemented in the plugin as of version 3.1.0.